# How to solve my pine code to make it work and not showing no data?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, no-data

I was coding a strategy using 3 ema and backtesting until it showed me no data error.Help my code doesn't work. It is showing no data and I don't know why

````
strategy('3 ema strategy', overlay=true, shorttitle='PSTES2', initial_capital=100000, default_qty_value=100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, commission_value=0.025)


start_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Date")
start_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Month")
start_year = input.int(defval = 2021, title = "Start Year")

end_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Date")
end_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Month")
end_year = input.int(defval = 2022, title = "End Year")

between_dates = (time >= timestamp(start_year, start_month, start_date, 1, 0) and (time < timestamp(end_year, end_month, end_date, 23, 59)))

currentPrice = ta.ema(close, 1)
openCondition1 = (ta.ema(close,20) == currentPrice)
openCondition2 = (ta.ema(close,50) < currentPrice)
openCondition3 = (ta.ema(close,200) < currentPrice)
openCondition4 = (ta.ema(close,200) < ta.ema(close,50))

// Exit Conditions
exitCondition1 = ta.ema(close, 50) < ta.ema(close, 200)

if between_dates
    strategy.entry("BTC enter", strategy.long, 1, when = openCondition1 and openCondition2 and openCondition3)
    strategy.close("BTC enter", when = exitCondition1)```
````

Answer (score 0):

1 - set correct `end_year`.

2 - fix `openCondition1`: currentPrice will not be equal to `ta.ema(close,20)`

code without openCondition1:

```
//@version=5
strategy('3 ema strategy', overlay=true, shorttitle='PSTES2', initial_capital=100000, default_qty_value=100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, commission_value=0.025)


start_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Date")
start_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Start Month")
start_year = input.int(defval = 2020, title = "Start Year")

end_date = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Date")
end_month = input.int(defval = 1, title = "End Month")
end_year = input.int(defval = 2030, title = "End Year")

between_dates = (time >= timestamp(start_year, start_month, start_date, 1, 0) and (time < timestamp(end_year, end_month, end_date, 23, 59)))

currentPrice = ta.ema(close, 1)
// openCondition1 = (ta.ema(close,20) == currentPrice)
openCondition2 = (ta.ema(close,50) < currentPrice)
openCondition3 = (ta.ema(close,200) < currentPrice)
openCondition4 = (ta.ema(close,200) < ta.ema(close,50))

// Exit Conditions
exitCondition1 = ta.ema(close, 50) < ta.ema(close, 200)

entryCond = openCondition2 and openCondition3

if entryCond and between_dates
    strategy.entry("BTC enter", strategy.long)

if exitCondition1 and between_dates
    strategy.close("BTC enter")
```